# How to design a spinner in Android

Tags: android-layout, android, android-spinner

I want to design a spinner as displayed in the image below:

[image]

I am not getting the arrow symbol pointing downside in spinner. How can I do this?

If I make a button design like shown above then I have to write extra code to get similar functionality as for a spinner, as Spinner doesn't have `android:drawableRight="@drawable/arraodown"`, but in the button we have this method.

Comment: I am using                                                 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_subject=new ArrayAdapter<String>(ActivityName.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,ArrayListData);
     spinner_name.setAdapter(adapter_subject);

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Do not mess around with right/left/... drawables.

Just set one 9-patch drawable as background that limits the inner content.

```
<Spinner
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/you_spinner_drawable" />
```

Regarding the 9-patch drawable have a look at the android resources or at this example picture taken from [this blog post](http://www.mokasocial.com/2011/03/easily-create-a-default-custom-styled-spinner-android/) (which shows in little more detail on how to make a custom spinner):

[image: spinner drawables example]

For information about 9-patch drawables see the android documentation:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch
http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html

Of course you can also specify a State list xml file as drawable, eg.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- When disabled -->
    <item android:state_enabled="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/your_disabled_spinner_drawable" />
    <!-- When selected -->
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/your_selected_spinner_drawable" />
    <!-- When not selected-->
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/your_default_spinner_drawable" />
</selector>
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList

Answer (score 3):

```
<Spinner
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/you_spinner_drawable" />

**You can use the below mentioned Drawable to set as background for this spinner**.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- When disabled -->
    <item android:state_enabled="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/your_disabled_spinner_drawable" />
    <!-- When selected -->
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/your_selected_spinner_drawable" />
    <!-- When not selected-->
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/your_default_spinner_drawable" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create a custom layout for the spinner. I think the following [XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) might give you an idea.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="3dip">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/number"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Illegal Exception is thrown, and it asks for `TextView` layout only. Have you got a working sample by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

Just use [GIMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIMP) as your image editor and change background color and border with a color you like.

For example, I did this image by editing an existing one I found on the Internet: http://sdrv.ms/1lRkTbG