# 9Patch content area error

Tags: android, nine-patch

It seems my content area doesn't match what the 9patch file says it should be
Heres my 9patch file.
[image: my-nine-patch-image]

and here is an image of how it looks with an item in it, **but the text is getting cut off prematurely**, it should be "Varenr." I don't understand **why there is such a big white space instead of text** ??
[image]

and here is the xml layout of the spinner:

```
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/sortSpinner"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/spinner_background"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:prompt="@string/sort" />
```

And of the spinner item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="none"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:singleLine="true" />
```

Thanks in advance for help.

And for closure, the 9patch in question:
[image: 9patch image]

**Edit:**
The whole line where the spinner is located:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/headerLabel"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="11">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sortAmountLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:textColor="@color/solid_red"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sortLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
                android:text="Produkter"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="@color/solid_red"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/filterBtn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:background="@drawable/button_background_red"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:onClick="setFilterList"
            android:text="Filtrér"
            android:textColor="@color/solid_white"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/sortSpinner"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:paddingRight="30dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/spinner_background"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:prompt="@string/sort" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Check : http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html

Comment: Does not work for my image, since i need it to stretch in 2 places (above and below the ">")

Comment: In 9-patch top and left side are indicate which area are stretched (one pixel is enough),bottom and right side are indicate content area.

Comment: @HareshChhelana I know, but it obviously doesnt work as you see above...

Comment: but the text is getting cut off prematurely, it should be "Varenr." I don't understand why there is such a big white space instead of text ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to design a spinner in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18074394/how-to-design-a-spinner-in-android)

Comment: @ShabbirDhangot It's not a duplicate of a simple question of how to. This is an issue of whitespace, I'll bold it in the Question description for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now, this is how I remade it:

[image]

Which gives this result:

[image]

Make sure the extension is **.9.png**

**[EDIT]**

This is the result when applied to a TextView:

[image]

The screen is an old ldpi device (240x320 @120 dpi)

This is how I applied it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/stripes_vert_4"
    >

    <!-- ... -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
        android:background="@drawable/spinner_drawable"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**[EDIT 2]**

As per the OP requirement, I switched the TextView to a Spinner:

Result:

[image]

By using this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/stripes_vert_4"
    >

    <!-- ... -->

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spnElements"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:entries="@array/prefs_search_modes"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="@drawable/spinner_drawable"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Which implies you have an `arrays.xml` file in your `value` folder.
Mine is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- Settings -->
    <!-- Word search mode -->
    <string-array name="prefs_search_modes">
        <item>*b* (Contains "b")</item>
        <item>Ab* (Starts with "Ab")</item>
        <item>*bc (Ends in "bc")</item>
        <item>Abc (Exact match)</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

**[EDIT3]**

In the last comments the OP is asking for (75% white space + the rest of the width left for the spinner) something like this:

[image]

**ARE YOU SURE**?

The running screen is low res (ldpi).
But next to it, in the graphical editor you can see another device (HTC Desire Bravo) screen which is **hdpi**.

And it shows the same "issue": `1/4 screen width`.
So, the stretchable part of the 9 png background (which contains the text) is squeezed away and only the unsqueezable part (the arrow) stays.

**[EDIT4]**

After playing with the 9 patch size, I could make part of the text become visible:

[image]

So, it seems you have to experiment with smaller sizes until you get an acceptable result.

**[EDIT5]**

I forgot to add the new spinner 9 patch (resized).
Here it is:

[image]

When rescaling, mind the outer border: it has to be **completely transparent** and the markers must be **full black**.

Comment: And you get get it to work as intended ? because I can't, i've tried with 1pixel above and below+ to the sides. no difference. There's still a huge space between the V and the text, even though there should not

Comment: I'll try with a TextView. Give me some minutes.

Comment: try and change it to a spinner please? :)

Comment: Done. Now it's using a Spinner.

Comment: Last request, squeeze the spinner to 3/11th of the screen size

Comment: 3/11 is about 3/12. So, 1/4. That is, 25%. You can easily use weights (in a LinearLayout or derivates - RelativeLayouts won't work).

Comment: It's okay, i just need you to make it smaller, because my spinners that take up all screen works as well.

Comment: Do you mean the popup or the "at rest" spinner?

Comment: the spinner without pressing it. Has nothing to do with its popup :)

Comment: So, you want it to be 1/4 of the screen height?

Comment: OK, I think I finally got it: Text Area = 75% and Down Arrow = 25%, right?

Comment: It makes no sense to me: having such a large wasted space and such a narrow spinner width?

Comment: Because if have other things that fills that area :)
Added the whole section of xml at the bottom of the question for you.

Comment: I edited my answer... **are you sure** you want something like that?

Comment: Naah it's because your screen is so low resolution, else downarrow would be smaller, and the text should show, and this is when i get the issue in topic

Comment: The running screen is low res (ldpi). But next to it in the graphical editor there is another device (HTC Desire Bravo) screen which is **hdpi**. And it shows the same issue: `1/4 screen width`.

Comment: A new experiment in sizing lead to some result... see my last edit.

Comment: Well fair, works on your devices, I'll accept answer to give you points, still don't know why it doesnt on mine though

Comment: What I showed in the **latest** pictures is a different 9 patch (**resized**). Wait, I'm posting it.